# Prevent perforce from toggling the execute bit for all users when checking in files

Tags: linux, permissions, perforce

How can I get perforce to retain the execute bit for all and not just for users and groups through the graphical client when checking in files?

Right now what I do is right click on the file `->` Change Filetype `->` then tick the `exec bit set in workspace option`. This does preserve the execute bit but only for the user and the file's group (to my understanding, it is the equivalent of the process described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326441/how-to-set-file-permission-bits-with-perforce) question).

How can I make it preserve the execute bit for all?

An illustration.

Before checking it in:

```
-rwxr-x--x  1 user group_name    0 Jul 20 14:14 test_file
         ^
```

After checking it in:

```
-r-xr-x---  1 user group_name    0 Jul 20 14:24 test_file
         ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `p4` respects your `umask` configuration, so this likely is a problem with your `umask`:

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx

$ p4 sync -f some_script
//depot/path/some_script#1 - refreshing /client/path/some_script

$ ls -algGF some_script
-r-xr-xr-x 1 0 Jul 21 04:13 some_script*

$ umask o=
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=

$ p4 sync -f some_script
//depot/path/some_script#1 - refreshing /client/path/some_script

$ ls -algGF some_script
-r-xr-x--- 1 0 Jul 21 04:14 some_script*
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the filetype to +x to set the executable bit automatically.

Comment: I did but it only affects user and group permissions, all permissions are still cleared.